# Sudden SQL syntax error after 1+ years of working - No upgrade

Tags: php, sql, syntax

For 1 year my company's software worked just fine. Out of the sudden this happens (And is costing us a lot of headache and money):

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'get FROM Acompanhamento WHERE alunoid = '2767' 
and excluido = 0 ORDER BY data de' at line 1' in /.../dao/DboObject.php:27
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /.../DboObject.php(27): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /.../AcompanhamentoAlunoDao.php(24): DboObject->select('SELECT id, peso...', Array)
#2 /.../AcompanhamentoAlunoBo.php(19): AcompanhamentoAlunoDao->select('alunoid = ? and...', Array)
#3 /.../ficha_de_acompanhamento.php(38): AcompanhamentoAlunoBo->getAcompanhamentoByAluno('2767')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /.../DboObject.php on line 27
```

Code in the files mentioned by the stack (lines that start and end with ** are the exact ones mentioned by the stack trace and I added that now for you guys to see):

DboObject.php:

```
public function select($sql='',$args){
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        **$this->query->execute($args);**
        $this->result = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

AcompanhamentoAlunoDao.php:

```
parent::select($sql, $args);
```

AcompanhamentoAlunoBo.php:

```
public function getAcompanhamentoByAluno($alunoId,$campo=null){
        **$query = "alunoid = ? and excluido = 0 ";**
        if(!is_null($campo)){
            $query.= "and ".$campo." is not null ";
        }
```

ficha_de_acompanhamento.php:

```
$acompanhamento = $acompanhamentoAlunoBo->getAcompanhamentoByAluno($AlunoId);
```

What's weird is that it worked for more then a year and I can't see nothing wrong with it. How can it have a syntax error out of nowhere?

Comment: As it is a database app, things change every time you write to the database. It could be a problem with corrupt data, data you didn't expect (for example excluido needs to be numeric), permissions in the database, etc. See if the query can actually be run against the database directly. That would be a start to debugging.

Comment: Nothing in your question references `get FROM Acompanhamento` please add the code related to the error message. Please include the `$args` definition.

Comment: echo the complete `$sql` and post here